# Postgres: more efficient to compare row as text or composite type?

Tags: sql, performance, postgresql, composite-types

I have two separate queries and I want to test for equality in a sproc. The queries return an integer and string as a pair.

My first approach resulted in comparing an aggregated array of text values, pulled from casting the row to text

```
FOR REC IN
   SELECT * FROM ...
LOOP
    var1 := array_append(my_var, REC::TEXT)
```

which compares as:

```
select var1 = (SELECT array_agg(x)::TEXT[] FROM (select ... ) x)
```

My second approach was to use an array of a custom type:

```
FOR REC IN
   SELECT x::my_type as r FROM (...) x
LOOP
   var1 := array_append(my_var, (REC.r))
```

which compares as:

```
select var1 = (SELECT array_agg(x::my_type) FROM (select ... ) x)
```

The text version was easier to write and didn't require cluttering the database with another type. The only thing the custom type version has going for it is that it might be faster to execute.

So that's my question, does a composite type execute more efficiently than just casting to text and using that instead? My concern is that the database converts the row to a string and then converts that string to the custom type behind the scenes which would actually make it slower.

Edit:

It would seem performance-wise there may not be a tangible difference in most applications. So a follow-up question would be: is there a downside to just doing the text comparison?

Comment: In my own rudamentary performance testing I don't notice any consistent difference between the two, which would make sense since I would think it would take a very large amount of data for there to make a noticeable difference.

Comment: [this looks like an XY problem] *what* are you trying to compare? (sets of records?) Please add some table definition+sample data + intended result to your question. Note: Generally speaking, loops (and arrays) are always a bad idea in SQL.